# phone mounts as media device not usb storage

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb-mass-storage

My Samsung Galaxy SII used to mount normally as a USB drive in Ubuntu until the 4.0.3 upgrade. Now the only two options are:

- connect as Media Device (MTP)
- connect as Camera (PTP)

neither of the above works properly with Ubuntu 12.04 so I could browse and manage files on the phone and the SD card.

Does Android 4.1 not support the device to be mounted as USB drive anymore?? I tried turning on USB Debugging in developer options but no difference...

Comment: Related: [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/218526)

Answer (score 6):

Actually, this is even easier: http://www.computerandyou.net/2012/01/how-to-fix-android-samsung-galaxy-s2-not-recognized-on-linux/

Android 4.0.3 does still have the USB Mass Storage feature, it's just hidden in "Other Network Settings" where one would not really expect it...

Answer (score 3):

UMS ([USB Mass Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass_storage_device_class)) was replaced by MTP somewhere with, at latest, ICS. Some kernels still may contain for UMS, but most won't anymore. So here are your options:

- Check the market for Apps which can enable UMS again (I heard mentioned a few who *should* be able doing so, including [AL Mass Storage Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=labs.antu.hw.storage), [USB Mass Storage Watcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skidmrk.umswatcher), and [Usb Host Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.sztupy.android.usbhostcontroller) -- but no guarantees whatsoever, as I didn't try any due to lack of ICS devices
- install the mtp packages on Ubuntu (`apt-get install mtp-tools`)

Some helpful information on the second point:

- [Connect your Android Ice Cream Sandwich](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access)
- [How to mount an MTP device as a drive](http://www.anythingbutipod.com/forum/showthread.php?t=32817)