# Need to mount htc one m7 as usb mass storage

Tags: usb-connection-mode

So I have read that android have removed the ability to use an android as a usb drive. I've read all the posts about how MTP is soooo much better. But unfortunately, in my case, none of this means anything if you can't get your pc to boot. For one reason or another when swapping up out a SSD, the system refuses to boot. No problem I though, just download a copy of Kali, mount the phone as a USB and boot from that. Apparently I am SOL, plenty of posts talking up the wonders of MTP, none of which remotely apply in this circumstance. As its a clean phone I'm booting off, it's not rooted so I can't use DriveDroid, and I can't root it without a pc.

Some two cents rant: I buy android specifically because they aren't easy to use, but because they are functional. This seems like a criminal dumbing down/Apple style walled garden of android. I mean why would you take away the ability to mount the phone as a drive; this is THE feature of android, being able to flash on OS as you go.

My question is: how can I use my droid, a htc one m7, to mount a Linux image so my pc can boot off it via USB. I have tried looking for it in bios, fiddling with numerous options, but apparently some wise guy at Google thought this wasn't an important feature. Hell even if there was a way to root the device from itself I could get somewhere.

Regards

Comment: I understand your frustration, but please edit your question so as to make it easily understandable. There are other places to vent frustrations :)  Why don't you use a flashdrive and change settings in BIOS on PC to load from there. Then reinstall. Since the PC (until its loaded) won't acknowledge the device, this seems to be off-topic. You may have to rephrase your question to keep from getting flagged.

Comment: Related: [How to enable SD MSC mount in Jelly Bean?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46358/16575) You also might wish to take a look at [these 12 questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=enable+usb+mass+storage+answers%3A1).