# Turning on USB mode in Galaxy Grand

Tags: usb-mass-storage, samsung-galaxy-grand

I have 2 mobile phones, a Samsung Galaxy S II and a Galaxy Grand. The Galaxy S2 has Android 2.3.6 and the Galaxy Grand has Android 4.2. When I am trying to connect the Grand to my PC, it gives me 2 options: MTP and Camera. MTP is media Transfer mode, and when I select it, restricts speed. On the other hand, the S2 has USB mode which works fine for me.

So is there any way that I can connect the Galaxy Grand with USB mode?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [phone mounts as media device not usb storage](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27283/phone-mounts-as-media-device-not-usb-storage) or [How can I use my Galaxy Nexus as an external USB storage drive?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26288/how-can-i-use-my-galaxy-nexus-as-an-external-usb-storage-drive).

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is rooted, try installing one of the "mass storage enabler" apps from the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=mass%20storage%20enabler&c=apps).